# Varibla image source issue

Tags: javascript, image, variables

when I run this code it initially cant find the source ***"src="colour[var x]" "*** but once I have used colourChange it works fine, I just need to fix this one issue. any help would be much appreciated.

much thanks

```
src=[var x]
```

Comment: `"colour[var x]"` is not a valid URL for an image. You are just making stuff up on the go.

Comment: the src attribute for an image takes a string that points to an html image ....not a javascript variable....

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables are not available in html elements attributes `src="colour[var x]"`. So you have to initialize `src` with valid path value, or you can initialize it in js

```
...
var colour = ["red.gif", "amber1.gif", "green.gif", "amber1.gif"];
document.getElementById("light").src = colour[0];
function colourChange(){
...
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was loking for thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Traffic Lights</title>
</head>
<body>

<img id="light" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeIlyurWoqEAMds0DmsxrFDr0R3bXCErkDAWGEnuUF757qN7uW" width="150px" height="150px">
<button onclick="colourChange()">Click Me To Cycle Through The Colours</button> 
<script>
var x=0;
var colour = ["https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeIlyurWoqEAMds0DmsxrFDr0R3bXCErkDAWGEnuUF757qN7uW", "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ7t30uQ_C4eV-HXMFZU2EPlqQ_MwsMA2kEfkzBFjC3Sav4OM3n", "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSNxgGXA3G2NwGVo70gZmy3ccYEcOSo4vzcPsgQRLbU_hGIBCWrnA", "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqFHvDm74NYMdbBtW-ZO9o3irXu4GHynOkDiCxDXJ484m1Ahyt"];
function colourChange(){
     x += 1;
    document.getElementById("light").src = colour[x];
    
    if (x == 3) x = 0;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```